# Add button 'action_open_quants' to inherited 'product.template' model - Odoo v8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have these fields on my class:

```
class bsi_production_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread','text.paper','product.template']

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string="Product")
    qty_available = fields.Float(string="Qty Available", related="product_id.qty_available")
```

Originally, on `stock` module You got this function:

```
class product_template(osv.osv):
    _name = 'product.template'
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    def action_open_quants(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        products = self._get_products(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
        result = self._get_act_window_dict(cr, uid, 'stock.product_open_quants', context=context)
        result['domain'] = "[('product_id','in',[" + ','.join(map(str, products)) + "])]"
        result['context'] = "{'search_default_locationgroup': 1, 'search_default_internal_loc': 1}"
        return result
```

Since I've inherited `product.template` on my custom module, I want to show this very same function on my view, so I just declared like this:

```xml
<field name="product_id"/>
<field name="qty_available"/>
<button class="oe_stat_button"
    name="action_open_quants"
    icon="fa-building-o"
    type="object">
```

Originally (on `stock` module), it is declared like this:

```xml
<button class="oe_stat_button"
    name="action_open_quants"
    icon="fa-building-o"
    type="object"  attrs="{'invisible':[('type', '=', 'service')]}" groups="stock.group_locations">
    <div><field name="qty_available_text"/></div>
</button>
```

Right now, it is partially working, since I can visualize the quants associated with the product I choose from Many2one and related fields, but it is not related to the product I dinamically choose on my view.

So, is there a way o get it work exactly as it is on `stock` module?

I hope I've explained myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the `_get_products` function in your module to return the products you want to show on quants view. One way I would do is to use context to pass the product_id to `_get_products` function

On your view:

```
<field name="product_id" context="{'product_tmpl_id': product_id}"/>
```

And in your `_get_products` function:

```
def _get_products(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    products = []
    context = context or {}
    product_tmpl_id = context.get('product_tmpl_id', False)
    if product_tmpl_id:
        prodtmpl = self.pool.get('product.template').browse(cr, uid, product_tmpl_id, context=None)
        if prodtmpl:
            products += [x.id for x in prodtmpl.product_variant_ids]
    else:
        products = #... call super here
    return products
```